# Show/hide child on parent click and grandchild on child click using CSS

Tags: html, css, angular, css-selectors, ngfor

I am displaying elements dynamically using Angular 6 *ngFor loop. 
I have a three-level architecture.
I want to show inner elements on parent element click and innermost elements on inner element click in ul-li-a structure.
ONLY use CSS.

The active link gets the .activeLink class

```
<ul id="myUL">
    <li *ngFor="let clientParent of sourceData;">
      <a class="caret" routerLinkActive="activeLink" routerLink="..">{{clientParent.shortName}}</a>
      <ul class="nested">
        <li *ngFor="let clientFund of clientParent.counterpartyFunds" class="list-none">
          <a routerLinkActive="activeLink" routerLink="..">{{clientFund.name}}</a>
          <ul class="inner">
            <li *ngFor="let fundAccount of clientFund.fundAccounts">
              <a routerLinkActive="activeLink" routerLink="..">
                {{fundAccount.shortName}}
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

CSS:

```
a.activeLink {
  color:red;
}

.nested {
  display: none;
}

a.activeLink + ul {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: With just CSS not possible, you can't use CSS to handle click events.

Answer (score 0):

In a case like yours I would try to make components representing the "Parent" and the "Child" relationship.
In your `Parent component` template you render your `Child component`(s).

Additionally define a service like `ShowChildrenService` and inject this in your Parent components.
You update the `ShowChildrenService` through a click event on some parent (you can also pass the 'id' of the parent if you'd like). Each parent will listen to these events and decide wether they should render their children.
You can also let the parent pass a variable to its children, which in their turn set a CSS class via the `[ngClass]` directive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, I used jQuery to toggle the your class nested" 
if you clicked the parent list it will toggle between show/hide the child list.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cg9ruao1/

## jQuery:

```
$('#myUL li').on('click', function (e) {
       $('ul#list').toggleClass('nested');
    });
```

## HTML

I also added a ID for the ul with the class nested to be triggered.

```
 <ul id="list" class="nested">
```